# como mostrar solo datos True en un foreign key de python

Tags: python, django-forms

models.py:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    user_create = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name = 'user_create')

upd.html:

...
<label class="control-label col-md-2">Creador</label>
<div class="col-md-7">
    {{ form.user_create }}
    <span style="color: red;">{{ form.user_create.errors }}</span>
</div>

views.py:

...
form = ArticleForm(request.POST, instance=articulo)
```

Comment: No me queda claro. ¿Quieres mostrar el control creador solo cuando `user_create` tenga datos?

Comment: Explica que quieres hacer... no se entiende nada, ademas, creeria conveniente que añadas el formulario de `ArticleForm`